# Can I expand and improve a Neural network model without retraining from scratch?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, classification

Say I have trained a Neural Network for classifying digits with the MNIST dataset. Could I somehow make use of the already trained neural network if I wanted to also be able to identify the character "A". The new model should end up being able to differentiate: "0-1-2-3-4-5-6-7-8-9-A"

I'm guessing I would need to change the neural network so it acommodates an extra possible output in the output layer.

I was thinking that maybe I could use the weights obtained in the initial model as the starting values for the corresponding weights in the new model. Would that be any useful at all or will I be better off just starting from scratch a new model?

I'm aware that Mnist is not a really big dataset and starting over would not be a big deal, but I think the question is still interesting and would become more relevant when working with bigger datasets or more complex systems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This process is called fine tuning
To do this you need to:

1. Find architecture you would like to fine tune (better to use [torch.models](https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/models.html)
2. Print the model to look on it's architecture
3. Usually torch models have last layer called `fc`, it's fully connected layer with `out_size == amount_of_classes`, you need to replace this fc layer with your own (in your example it will be layer with 11 outputs).
4. After that you need to freeze weights in most part of model (because MNIST is really small dataset and big model can't be well fitted on it, if dataset bigger you can freeze less weights). To freeze weights, you have to iterate through layers and write something like `layer.params.requires_grad = False`
5. After that you need to train model as you usually do (torch lightning or manually).

Generally speaking fine tuning is pretty popular practice and it helps to spend much less time on fitting